# jquery resizable with absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following problem:
I need to make my div re-sizable, but it needs to be located on right bottom of the page.
When I use jquery resizable function and position: absolute, div jumps around...

[Sample](http://jsbin.com/zakelozoxa/1/)

Code:

```
$('#resizable').resizable({
  handles: {
    'nw': '#nwgrip',
    'n': '#ngrip',
    'w': '#wgrip'
  }
});

  <div id='resizable'>
    <div id='content'>
      Im Resizable!
    </div>
    <!-- Define corners -->
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" id="nwgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" id="ngrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" id="wgrip"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code should be added to question content.

Comment: It works with Firefox, but it doesn't on Chrome...

Comment: Here you go. Its fixed in this - http://jsbin.com/dixurozeru/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that resizable uses `top` `left` `with` and `height` to set the element's position.

Now yours is positioned with `right` and `bottom` at the beginning, so the moment the resizable updates the position, `right` will be deleted and `left` will be set. (to 0 because it doesn't exist).

So you'll have to calculate the `left` position at page load or maybe on resize `start`

Comment: Indeed it works using `top` and `left`: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/zisetokahu/1/edit?html,css,output)